# Display Content After Google+1 Button Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus, google-plus-one

I thought some special content for those who share my content in social media would be great and started working on this thing.

I managed to get it working with Facebook Likes and Twitter Tweets, but stuck in Google+1.

The information here didn't helped much: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1366830

Can anyone tell me how do I register a +1 and display content (hidden div) immediately after the +1?

Here are the codes I am using:

HTML

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" callback="cpg1callback"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
function cpg1callback(data){
      if (data.state == 'on') {
        $('.gpsuccessmsg').show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 500);
      }
}
```

I have placed that JS Code in a js file linked at header and that is not working, I also tried placing that js code just before closing body tag with no success. Any guidance here will be very helpful.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I got it working at last, after spending a couple of hours. Sharing this as it might help someone looking for answers on the same issue.

You need to have the callback (functionname) within `callback` attribute in case of default +1 button markup to make the call back work. For example, the +1 button code should be:

```
<g:plusone size="medium" callback="cpg1callback"></g:plusone>
```

In case of HTML5 Valid Syntax, the attribute should be `data-callback`. For Example:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-callback="cpg1callback"></div>
```

I hope this will save you some time.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the attribute `data-callback` instead of `callback` since you are using div tags. See the documentation at https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#plusonetag for details.